# Base64 encoding and decoding using different libraries

Tags: java, android, encoding, base64, decoding

I'm sending some data from Android client using built-in Base64 class:

```
String auth = android.util.Base64.encodeToString ("someusername:somepassword".getBytes ("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
```

This creates an Encoded string: c29tZXVzZXJuYW1lOnNvbWVwYXNzd29yZA==

But when I try to decode this on Server, using a different library:

```
String auth = com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64.decode (header).toString ();
```

I get: [B@5c92ac1c

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong here? I cannot import Android's util to my Server code.

Apologies if I'm missing something very trivial...

Comment: the encoded string does match "someusername:somepassword", so there must be something you're missing in the apache Base64 (either how to pass it a parameter, or how to handle the return value). It does say internal-security in the package, so maybe it's not exactly what you'd hope it to be? Also, consider this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111577/package-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-security-utils-base64-does-not-exist

Comment: Sure that `header` contains the Base64 data?

Comment: @ThomasW. or that.. :)

Comment: Yes, I'm definitely receiving the same encoded string on my server. In fact, what's more wierd is that I don't get the actual values using android.util.Base64.decode() too.

Answer (score 0):

It was something really basic, as I feared. I didn't explicitly define on the receiving end that I'm decoding UTF-8 data. Here's what I did to solve it:

```
String auth = new String(header, "UTF-8");
```