# BASE64 Finish project error

Tags: java, base64

Have this import in my proyecto `import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;` but when i go to build and clean with netbeans it give me error,

error: package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils does not exist
Code where Base64 needed: 
`String encryptedStr = Base64.encode(encrypted, Base64.BASE64DEFAULTLENGTH);`

How can i solve this, need i add a external jar to the proyect ?

Thx for all

Comment: possible duplicate of [Package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64 does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111577/package-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-security-utils-base64-does-not-exist)

Comment: Solution given there don't work for me.

Comment: Did you look at the comments to the solution? There is an official Base64 class in Java8. Use that.

Comment: But i'm actually using 1.7, but ok will try with java 8

Answer (score 0):

For an extra jar read this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19743851/base64-java-encode-and-decode-a-string/26530642#26530642)

or You can use

```
javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter methods accordingly
DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary() and DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary
```

Comment: i finally downloaded org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64; and its work but i need to to some changes to get it work but now its work