# How to solve com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security package does not exist in netbean javafx application

Tags: java, xml, apache, netbeans

I want to build .jar in NetBean 8.0.2.

I have developed a small project based javafx application.
My project uses packages such as `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security`, `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.c14n` and `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils`.
My project runs well at Netbean without warning or error.
But When I build this project as jar file, following error is occurred:

```
**error: package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security does not exist**

**error: package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.c14n does not exist**

**error: package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils does not exist**
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your project uses [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/), add Maven dependency [`com.sun.xml.security:xml-security-impl:1.0`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.security/xml-security-impl/1.0) to your Maven project file (`pom.xml`).

Comment: I did just that, ran copy-dependencies and still the same error on compile, what gives?

Comment: Where is the source for that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `xml-security-impl.jar` to your classpath.

Comment: My project success.
You are great.

Comment: Hi, Jens.
I have a problem.
I have download xml-security-impl.jar from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlsecurity104jar.htm
and insert to my project library.
So, project build is success, but project running error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/Expression
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xpath.Expression
Help me again.
Thanks regards.

Comment: @LinRenHua You need the `xalan.jar` too.

Comment: Thanks for you effort.
You are right.
After xalan.jar inserted, org/apache/xpath/Expression error disappeared.
But another error org/apache/xpath/compiler/FuncLoader occured.
I think that some jar files are needed.
Would you like to contact with skype?
I wish to you help me again.
My Skype: renhua905@outlook.com
regards.

Comment: @LinRenHua Sorry no skype.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading xmlsec-x.y.z.jar (eg. xmlsec-1.4.0.jar) and adding it to project libraries, resolved the issue.

Answer (score -2):

You have used a package which should not be used. It has already been clarified here on SO and many places that any class within package starting from `com.sun` must not be used, as they can be removed in later versions of Java, without replacement.

More information on this : [Package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64 does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111577/package-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-security-utils-base64-does-not-exist)

To resolve your problem, you should use some other library.

Comment: Thanks for your effort.
Would you like to give "some other library" download urls?