# Base64 aes encoding / decoding

Tags: java, encryption, base64, aes

Our library used `import com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64;`

and it seems we are encouraged to use something else
 `import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;`
([Package com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.security.utils.Base64 does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111577/package-com-sun-org-apache-xml-internal-security-utils-base64-does-not-exist))

Thing is you have to change your encrypt/decrypt code as well, and I'm not sure how I should change them.
As of now, I get `Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher` error

([Encrypt and decrypt with AES and Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954611/encrypt-and-decrypt-with-aes-and-base64-encoding))

Anyone care to show the right way to do this? or I strongly suspect there should be a git repo that does this but couldn't find it..

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
 import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

 @Service
 public class SecureModule {
     private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
     public static byte[] ivBytes = { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
     public static final String Decrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception
     {
         byte[] textBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(text);
         //byte[] textBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
         AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
         SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
         return new String(cipher.doFinal(textBytes), "UTF-8");
     }
     public static final String DecryptAndBase64(String text, String key) throws Exception
     {
         byte[] textBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(text);
         //byte[] textBytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
         AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
         SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
         Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
         cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
         String Result="";
         // tried but doens't work
         //    Result = new String(cipher.doFinal(new Base64().decode(text.getBytes())), "UTF-8");

         Result = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(new String(cipher.doFinal(textBytes), "UTF-8").getBytes()));
         return Result;
=    }
     public static final String Encrypt(String text, String key) throws Exception
     {
         byte[] textBytes = text.getBytes("UTF-8");
         AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
              SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
              Cipher cipher = null;
         cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
 //      cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
         byte[] sResult = cipher.doFinal(textBytes);
         String ssResult = Base64.encodeBase64String(sResult);
         return ssResult;
     }
     public static final String EncryptAndBase64(String text, String key) throws Exception
     {
        String plaintext = "";
         plaintext = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(text.getBytes()));
         byte[] textBytes = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");
         AlgorithmParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivBytes);
              SecretKeySpec newKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
              Cipher cipher = null;
         cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
         cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, newKey, ivSpec);
         return Base64.encodeBase64String(cipher.doFinal(textBytes));
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you get that error? And please show some example data.

Comment: For instance, DecryptAndBase64, I get error at cipher.doFinal(textBytes); encrypted `text` variable looks like "MTExMTExMTE="

Comment: 12 Base64 encoded characters with one padding character means it encodes a byte array of length 8, 8 is not a valid input for AES/CBC. It's also not possible that this ciphertext is actually produces by the encryption code that you've shown here.